# Merging hashes in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to merge two hashes. Well, I am able to merge, but the output is not the way I want it to be:

Here is my code:

```
my %friend_list = (
   Raj       => "Good friend",
   Rohit     => "new Friend",
   Sumit     => "Best Friend",
   Rohini    => "Fiend",
   Allahabad => "UttarPradesh",
);

my %city = (
    Bangalore => "Karnataka",
    Indore    => "MadhyaPradesh",
    Pune      => "Maharashtra",
    Allahabad => "UP",
);

my %friends_place = ();
my ($k, $v);
foreach my $ref (\%friend_list, \%city) {

    while (($k,$v) = each (%$ref)) {

        if (exists $ref{$k}) {

            print"Warning: Key is all ready there\n";
            next;
        } 
        $friends_place{$k} = $v;
    }  
}

while (($k,$v) = each (%friends_place)) {

    print "$k = $v \n";
}
```

From this o/p is

```
Raj=Good friend
Indore=MadhyaPradesh
Rohit=new Fiend
Bangalore=Karnataka
Allahabad=UttarPradesh
Sumit=Best Friend
Pune=Maharashtra
Rohini =Fiend
```

But I want to print **%friend_list first** followed by **%city**.
Another thing which I was trying to do is, if there is any duplicate key, then it should give me a warning message. But it is not giving me any message. As we can see here, we have Allahabad in both hash.

Thanks

Comment: Do you just need all keys from the first hash before all keys from the second? Or do the keys of these hashes also need to be sorted in some way? Either way you need to use an array to keep the order, as a hash does not keep any (insertion or alphabetic) by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `if (exists $ref{$k}) {` is wrong and you can see it if you're putting `use strict; use warnings;` at the begining of the script.

Moreover this line should be `if (exists $friends_place{$k}) {` to produce the message about duplicate keys.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
my %firend_list = (
   Raj       => "Good friend",
   Rohit     => "new Fiend",
   Sumit     => "Best Friend",
   Rohini    => "Fiend",
   Allahabad => "UttarPradesh",
);

my %city = (
    Bangalore => "Karnataka",
    Indore    => "MadhyaPradesh",
    Pune      => "Maharashtra",
    Allahabad => "UP",
);
#merging
my %friends_place = ( %friend_list, %city );
```

And, for warnings:

```
foreach my $friend( keys %friend_list ){
 print"Warning: Key is all ready there\n" if $friend ~~ [ keys %city ];

}
```

Comment: +1 for the ~~ notification. It been using if (defined $city{$friend}) forever, mirroring if (defined($ARGV[0])), but it's good to save keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

As hashes are unordered, you need to use an array to store the ordering:

```
my %friends_place = (%firend_list, %city);
my @friends_place_keyorder = ((keys %firend_list), (keys %city));
if ((scalar keys %friends_place) != (scalar @friends_place_keyorder)) {
    print 'duplicate key found';
}
foreach (@friends_place_keyorder) {
    print "$_ = $friends_place{$_}\n";
}
```

**EDIT**: my original solution in python, left here for historical purpose:

As hashes are unordered, you need to use an array to store the ordering. I don't know perl, so the following code is python (should be fairly straightforward to translate to perl):

```
friend_list = ...
city = ...
friends_place = dict(friend_list.items() + city.items())
friends_place_keyorder = friend_list.keys() + city.keys()

# detect duplicate keys by checking their lengths
# if there is duplicate then the hash would be smaller than the list
if len(friends_place) != len(friends_place_keyorder): 
    print "duplicate key found"

# iterate through the list of keys instead of the hashes directly
for k in friends_place_keyorder:
    print k, friends_place[k]
```

Comment: @TudorConstantin: that is correct, as noted in my answer, I don't know enough about perl to make specifics. But the approach should be the same in both languages. As noted in your answer, I believe in perl you'd use the comma operator instead of the plus operator to merge the dicts and construct the key lists; and len() is done by prepending $ to the array name.